# Passing string through ajax function to the page where it gets echoed, PHP, AJAX, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, parameters

I have three files. test1.php, test2.php, and ajax.php. In test1.php, I have an text input. When I type something in the text input, it calls the ajax function, and pass whatever I type in the text input to test2.php as POST. After echoing it in text2.php, it shows up below the text input in test1.php.

Now, I want to pass a string through the **ajax function** to test2.php, before echoing it, so it'll show up below the text input in test1.php. For example, I want to pass the word "Hello" through the ajax function to test2.php - how would I be able to do that, or is that even possible? Thank you.

**test1.php**

```
<?php

include('ajax.php');

echo "<input type = 'text' name = 'text' onkeyup = 'ajax(\"test2.php\",\"input\",\"text\",\"output\")'>";
echo "<div id = 'output'/>";

?>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php

$text = $_POST['text'];
echo $text;

?>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function ajax(gotoUrl,type,inputName,output) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: gotoUrl,
           data: { select: $(type+'[name='+inputName+']').val()},
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( output ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}

</script>
```

Comment: I've read this over like 5 times and I don't get what your problem is or what you are trying to do....

Comment: @DaveChen I want to pass a string through the ajax function to test2.php, before echoing it, so it'll show up below the text input in test1.php. Through the ajax function, not through the text input.

Comment: @DaveChen Nothing wrong with the code itself. I just used it as an example of what an ajax function can do. My actual question is in the second paragraph.

Comment: @Rasclatt I want to pass a string through the ajax function to test2.php, before echoing it, so it'll show up below the text input in test1.php. Through the ajax function, not through the text input.

Comment: So you have the ajax working with the `keyup` input, but you want to have it autoload (or be triggered somehow) using a string as one of the arguments to the function?

Comment: I think @DaveChen has what you want to do, if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very possible.

**In ajax.php:**  Add a new element to your `data:{}` array:

`data: { select: $(type+'[name='+inputName+']').val(), some_string: 'Hello' },`

**In test2.php:**  You can now reference the 2nd element sent from your ajax request:

```
<?php

$text = $_POST['select'];
$some_string = $_POST['some_string'];
echo $some_string.$text;

?>
```

Comment: By the way, `text1.php` needs a closing `</div>` tag.  :)

Comment: Yeah! This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm glad someone understands what I was trying to ask for! You're awesome, dude! ;P

Comment: And @DaveChen got pissed that his answer was the wrong one, deleted it, and downvoted me. Wow, just wow.

Comment: I upvoted it and it should be upvoted even more, because this is a very strong and important javascript concept for those working with XMLHttpRequest, and it will likely help other users in the future.